LidR - Reading individual .las files but not ctg
I am attempting to use the tern LiDAR workflow = - https://github.com/ternaustralia/drone_lidar/blob/main/drone_lidar_workflow_testing.Rmd

All working fine until this section:

Create LASCatalog
ctg <- readLAScatalog(in_dir)

# create lax files for spatial indexing if not done already
if(length(list.files(path = in_dir, pattern = "\\.lax$")) == 0) 
  {lidR:::catalog_laxindex(ctg)}

# quality check - las file or catalog?
# TEST THIS 
# https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351821/capture-and-parse-output-of-lascheck-from-lidr
# las_check(las, FALSE)
# parse errors and warnings?


I have attempted to resolve the in_dir path and normalise - however I am getting the following errors:

> in_dir <- "~Documents\\data\\mtd\\test-las"
> # Normalize the directory path
> normalized_path <- normalizePath(in_dir, winslash = "/", mustWork = FALSE)
> print(normalized_path)
[1] "/Users/*****/biomassprojectsv1/~Documents\\data\\mtd\\test-las"
> if (!dir.exists(in_dir)) {
+   stop("The directory does not exist.")
+ } else {
+   print("The directory exists.")
+ }
[1] "The directory exists."

> mycsf <- csf(sloop_smooth=FALSE, cloth_resolution = 0.2, iterations = 500, class_threshold = 0.1)
> ctg <- readLAScatalog(in_dir)
Error: File not found
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(file) : path[1]=NA

I had success in the previous commandline and producing a plot from a function, so I know it is reading my individual .las file when called.
I am an amateur so forgive me if I am missing something really silly - I have asked chat gpt about 10 times to fix the code and each time the error still occurs so it must be something in my set up that I can't identify?

I fixed my own problem

restarted my environment and changed the start of the workflow from

out_dir = r"(F:\your\file\path\here)" # tmp folder for intermediate results (chunk 
outputs - delete on checking results) 
tmp_dir = r"(F:\your\file\path\here)" 

to the following:
n_dir <- path.expand("your\file\path\here") 
out_dir <- file.path(in_dir, "output") # Example output directory tmp_dir <- file.path(in_dir, "tmp") 

# Create the output directory if it does not exist if (!dir.exists(out_dir)) { dir.create(out_dir) } if (!dir.exists(tmp_dir)) { 

dir.create(tmp_dir) } # List files in the input directory files <- list.files(in_dir, pattern = "\\.las$", full.names = TRUE) print(files) 


Welcome to GIS SE. AS a new user, please take the [Tour]. We encourage those who find the answer to their Question to post an Answer to that Question. If you answer your own question within the Question, it is considered defacing the Question content, and is likely to be down-voted, rolled back, and or closed as not reproducible. Answers good, "I fixed it" edits bad.

Yes. Please remove the answer from the question and post it as an answer and then after 24h accept that answer.

Hi there. If you fixed your problem please put the solution as an answer. Thanks.
